# Error: Could not convert string to float

Tags: python, type-conversion

This is my code. I want to read the data from "data.txt" and convert it to type `float`, but there is a problem converting the data. The error says " could not convert string to float: ".

```
def CrearMatriz():
    archi = open("data.txt", "r")
    num = archi.readlines() 
    for lines in num:
        nums= [float(x) for x in lines.strip().split(",")]
    return nums
Numero = CrearMatriz()
```

The file contains  numbers separated by commas.

Comment: Could you give us an idea of how the data in `data.txt` is organized? E.g. paste the 5 first lines or something.

Comment: try: `float('Luis')`, `float(' ')`, `float('\n')` on your system, you will understand

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, but according to OP, his file doesn't contain any of those things. It only contains numbers and commas. Even the newlines are removed by `strip()`.

Comment: wrap `nums=...` in a try/except block and print the offending line. you likely have an empty line that splits to `['']`.

Comment: Check to see if you have a blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: You also don't need readlines you can iterate over the file object

Comment: @Kevin: The newlines are removed by `readlines()`, so there aren't any to remove by the time it gets to `strip()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - newlines are not removed by `readlines`.

Comment: My mistake; I thought it was equivalent to a `split()` on `\n`.

Comment: How many lines in the file?  Even if your code did not have this error, you would only return the numbers from the last line read because you keep overwriting nums in the `for` loop.

Comment: more generally, you need to consider how strict the rules for `data.txt` are. If its just _"The file contains numbers separated by commas."_, then the exception is a legitimate error. Your code reads and converts multiple lines but only returns the last, which makes it hard to guess what you want.

Comment: The file  have numbers separated by commas, for example 3.44,23,44.566,22,1,5.67  I want to save this  numbers like float. The file contains 1217x1017 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce this is by having a blank line at the end of the file.  So my data file looks like this:

```
12.34 , 56.78 , 90.12 , 34.56
```

There's a blank line after it, but I can't display that!  So here it is in another format:

```
od -xc data.txt
0000000      3231    332e    2034    202c    3635    372e    2038    202c
           1   2   .   3   4       ,       5   6   .   7   8       ,    
0000020      3039    312e    2032    202c    3433    352e    0a36    000a
           9   0   .   1   2       ,       3   4   .   5   6  \n  \n    
0000037
```

Note the `\n\n` near end-of file.

Try this code:

```
def CrearMatriz():
    archi = open("data.txt", "r")
    num = archi.readlines() 
    for line in num:
        line=line.strip()
        if line:
            nums=[float(x) for x in line.split(",")]
    return nums
Numero = CrearMatriz()
```

However, that does not work if you have more than one line of numbers!  It will only return the last line of numbers.  So this might be better (depending on what you need):

```
def CrearMatriz():
    nums = []

    for line in open("data.txt", "r"):
        line=line.strip()
        if line:
            nums.extend([float(x) for x in line.split(",")])
    return nums
Numero = CrearMatriz()
```

If you want a list of lists, then change the `extend` to `append`.

Comment: This could all be done using a list comprehension iterating over the file object, also using with is a better way to open files.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, but I wanted to keep to the original code as much as possible so the OP can see the changes.  If you try to do too many changes then it can be just white-noise to someone who is inexperienced.  My philosophy is to change as little as possible in a single answer.

Comment: I think getting into the habit of using with or at least closing the files is important.

Comment: If you try writing to a file in a loop and then opening the file to read the content before closing it you will see a problem, there are  numerous other times when closing causes issues but as you said this is not the time or place.

Comment: We are reading, not writing.  The file object is closed on exit from `for`, even on error (test it).  Anyway, I think it is more important to answer the guy's question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying it's the perfect answer, but I suggest you do your parsing outside of the list comprehension proper and append to nums on success, at least until your formatting fixes everything.

From looking at the errors I am getting, one possibility is that it looks like lines.strip() doesn't account for blank lines in your file.

```
def CrearMatriz():
    archi = open("data.txt", "r")
    num = archi.readlines() 
    for lines in num:
        nums= [float(x) for x in lines.strip().split(",")]
    return nums

def CrearMatriz2():
    with open("data.txt", "r") as archi:
        #having it in a separate function allows more robust formatting
        #and error handling.  append to nums on success
        def tofloat(nums, x, lines, cntr):
            try:
                res = float(x)
                assert isinstance(res, float)
                nums.append(float(x))
            except Exception, e:
                msg = "exception %s on field:%s: for line #%s:%s:" % (e, x, cntr,lines)
                print (msg)
                return

        nums = []
        num = archi.readlines() 
        for cntr, lines in enumerate(num):
            [tofloat(nums, x, lines, cntr) for x in lines.strip().split(",")]
        return nums

data="""
0.12,30.2,30.5,22
3,abc,4

"""


with open("data.txt","w") as f_test:
    f_test.write(data)


try:
    print "\n\ncalling CrearMatriz"
    Numero = CrearMatriz()
    print "\nCrearMatriz()=>", Numero
except Exception, e:
    print e


try:
    print "\n\ncalling CrearMatriz2"
    Numero = CrearMatriz2()
    print "\nCrearMatriz2()=>", Numero
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

and this gives...

```
calling CrearMatriz
could not convert string to float:


calling CrearMatriz2
exception could not convert string to float:  on field:: for line #0:
:
exception could not convert string to float: abc on field:abc: for line #2:3,abc,4
:
exception could not convert string to float:  on field:: for line #3:
:

CrearMatriz2()=> [0.12, 30.2, 30.5, 22.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm interested in the type of

```
lines.strip().split(",")
```

It seems to me that strip() should work on a string, but lines would be a list of strings. You might need a double comprehension, something like:

```
[[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(",")] for line in lines]
```

Without your data, I can't verify this, though.

You might try removing the float(x) and just using

```
nums= [x for x in lines.strip().split(",")]
print(nums)
```

to see what the exact values are that float(x) is choking on.

Comment: This is a suggestion for debug and not an answer.

Comment: In the question, `num` is a `list` of strings, and `lines` is a string. Not very good variable names, but there you have it.